# PHP script stops without error message (Which error type?)

Tags: php, xdebug

a PHP script stops without an error message, if I change the signature of a method of a class, which implements a intereface, e.g.:

```
interface A
{
  public function somefunction();
}

class B implements A
{
  public function somefunction(XY $xy);
  {
   ... 
  }
}
```

This is an error of course, but there is no error message shown.

What is the name of this error type? (I already searched a lot, but with the wrong phrases obviously)
How can I log or output this error?

I'm using PHP 5.3.1 (with XAMPP for Windows 1.7.3)

(I used Zend Debugger with PHP < 5.3 earlier, where those erros were shown in the Eclipse console, but now I'm using XDebug.)

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: have you checked your `error_log`

Answer (score 8):

put at the top of file and then try,

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

If you still getting no output, please check your error_log.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED

**@ontrack** Thanks, your hint directed me to the right direction:

I'm using an autoload function to load required classes (by using spl_autoload_register()). My implemention of my autoloader restrains all error messages... I did not know, that this causes such 'deeper' errors not to show up. 
This was at least kind of stupid from my side, but I'm more happy, that I found the reason for this problem and I have learned something :-)

Many thanks to all your contributions! And sorry again, that I cannot edit my initial question anymore.

**@outis** Thanks, please read my comment

Comment: @outis Thank you for this information! This is an important hint for my analysis. I'll try to update to this PHP version (XDebug version is 2.1 already).

(It seems, that I cannot edit my initial question, because I added it with a guest account, now I'm answering with a new 'real' account)

Comment: @askkirati: In General: You need to set up your php.ini accordingly. But the problem for me in this question was, that I suppressed error messages in one function by using `@include somefile.php` instead of `include somefile.php`

Answer (score 0):

Put the following at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

It should report an error.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be up with your configuration. When I try the sample code under PHP 5.3.2+XDebug 2.1.0, PHP complains:

> Fatal error:  Declaration of B::somefunction() must be compatible with that of A::somefunction()

The type of error is a [substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation, since a `B` can't be substituted for an `A` in all situations.